# Searching XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml that I want to search and return a child node in C#.

For example

```
<STOCK>
   <STOCKNAME name="Microsoft">     
      <STOCKSYMBOL>MSFT</STOCKSYMBOL>
   </STOCKNAME>
   <STOCKNAME name="Apple Inc.">        
       <STOCKSYMBOL>AAPL</STOCKSYMBOL>
   </STOCKNAME>
   <STOCKNAME name="Google">        
       <STOCKSYMBOL>GOOG</STOCKSYMBOL>
   </STOCKNAME> 
</STOCK>
```

If I pass the string Microsoft, I want to get a return of MSFT only. I think Im doing this wrong

```
String stockText = "";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\xml\stockname2.xml");

while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
             break;

        case XmlNodeType.Text:
             if (reader.GetAttribute("name") == stock) 
             {
                stockText = reader.GetAttribute("symbol");
             }
             break;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using a Linq2Xml instead? By using Linq it's far more intuitive.

Comment: If this is a personal project and you are not limited you should be using Linq to Xml

Comment: I will try this. Any direction is appreciative. Im new to this.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once you find one that gets you going down a path that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call it "wrong" because you could make that work, but it is definitely not the best approach. You would in essence be re-writing something called XPath which is [built into the .net framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115.aspx) (and is a [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) supported by many parsers)

You can reduce your code to something like:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"C:\xml\stockname2.xml");

var node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//STOCK/STOCKNAME[@name = 'Microsoft']/STOCKSYMBOL");
string symbol = node.InnerText; // this should be "MSFT"
```

Comment: XPath and Linq to Xml are both good approaches. XPath is more old school and you'll see a lot of .net examples moving to Linq to Xml. I prefer XPath because well, I'm old.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to "search XML" is to use XPath and/or XQuery.  This is fully supported in C# (and all .Net languages).

Here are some examples:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1182136.aspx/1
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333

Comment: stock is just a string i will be searching by. ie "Microsoft"

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq2Xml

```
string searchFor="Microsoft";
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(.....);

var result =  xDoc.Descendants("STOCKNAME")
    .Where(x=>x.Attribute("name").Value==searchFor)
    .Select(x=>x.Element("STOCKSYMBOL").Value)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: No worries, thank you for the help. You have got my mind thinking on some conecpts

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other posters that XPath and a document-oriented approach is the better way to go, but for the purposes of understanding the code you have written, here we go:

When you hit the Element that matches the company you're looking for, you then want to *advance* to the Text node and get *its* value.  Something like this:

```
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                if (reader.GetAttribute("name") == stock)
                {
                    if (reader.Read() && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                    {
                        stockText = reader.Value;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

(Apologies for any Javaisms that have crept into my C#.)

The reason that I prefer document-oriented solutions is that you can load the XML once and query it many times (for many stocks, in your case).  With an XmlTextReader, you get just one pass through the file.

Comment: See I am a JAva programmer as well, so no need to apologize :) I will try this approach as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not very robust, but I would do something as simple as this:

```
String stock = "Microsoft";
String stockText = "";
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\xml\stockname2.xml");

while(reader.ReadToFollowing("STOCKNAME"))
{
    if(reader.GetAttribute("name") == stock)
    {
        reader.ReadToDescendant("STOCKSYMBOL");
        stockText = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
        break;
    }
}
```

As long as your XML doesn't vary much it should work fine.